# How to capture and compare all object properties on a web page

Tags: qtp

I'm working on a web-based application. I would like to check properties for all objects on the page, but would rather not have to do them individually.

I remember test-tools past that would allow you could capture the whole page and select which objects and properties you wanted to keep track of.

Does QTP allow you to capture a whole page worth of object properties?

Answer (score 1):

Found this: http://relevantcodes.com/qtp-verify-multiple-object-properties-an-elegant-approach/

I hope it will help you..

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand the question then you should do the following:

1. Open Object Repository Manager
2. Run Object->Navigate and Learn (or press F6)
3. Then you can define a filter (if necessary), select browser and press "Learn"

Answer (score -1):

You can write a small script to do that.